# How do we search for files which contain a specific word and end in a specific file-type suffix?

Tags: powershell, regex, images, pictures, image-processing

How do we use Microsoft Windows  [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) and [Regular Expressions (Regex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in order to find all of the ***pictures*** (image files) on a computer such that the file name contains the word "***dog***".

We wish to consider many different file suffixes, not just `.jpg`:

```
.ACAD
.AFD
.AFP
.AOM
.AOMA
.APNG
.ASCII
.AVIF
.AVIFAV
.BMP
.BPG
.CABAC
.CDEC
.CDR
.CDRAW
.CGM
.CHEVC
.CIEC
.CIPA
.CMYK
.COLLADA
.CRT
.CWC
.DEEP
.DGN
.DML
.DRAW
.DXFDXF
.DXML
.ECW
.EMF
.EPS
.ERDAS
.EXIF
.FAMF
.FCCBY
.FDRW
.FIFF
.FITS
.FLIF
.FPGF
.FRIFF
.FVRML
.FXD
.GEM
.GIF
.GIMP
.GLE
.GMNG
.GMPEG
.GPNG
.GSVG
.HDR
.HEIF
.HEVC
.HPGL
.HSF
.HVIF
.ICC
.ICO
.IESC
.IESCD
.IGES
.ILBM
.IMAGINE
.IMAGINE
.IMG
.IMML
.INDD
.IPA
.ISGI
.ISO
.JFIF
.JFIFJPEG
.JPEG
.JPEGHDR
.JPEGJPEG
.JPG
.JPL
.JPS
.KKRA
.LCM
.LPCL
.LXAML
.LZW
.LZWLZW
.MANIAC
.MDP
.MEMF
.MML
.MOV
.MPO
.MSID
.MSIDSID
.MWMF
.NAPLPS
.NASA
.OBJ
.OCR
.ODG
.OGEX
.OGL
.PAM
.PBM
.PCB
.PCLIP
.PCPT
.PCX
.PDF
.PGFTZ
.PGM
.PGML
.PICT
.PLBM
.PLY
.PNG
.PNM
.PNS
.POVR
.PPDN
.PPM
.PPSP
.PRC
.PSD
.PST
.PXMP
.QCC
.RAW
.RGBE
.RGIS
.RIFF
.RISCOS
.RSX
.SAI
.SAISAI
.SISO
.STEP
.STL
.SUSKP
.SVG
.SVGC
.SWF
.SXML
.TARGA
.TGATGA
.TIF
.TIFF
.TVG
.TVP
.VDI
.VICAR
.VML
.VRML
.WEBP
.WMF
.WPM
.XCF
.XGL
.XISF
.XML
.XMP
.XPS
.XVL
```

Somthing like this in powershell?

```
PS > dir | ?{$_.name -match "^[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}.jpg$"}
```

Comment: Use PowerGrep https://www.powergrep.com/ (15 days free trial)

Comment: Do you have to limit it to these specific extensions or not? The question is very confusing as the request is very different from the shown regex.

Comment: I'd do something like this: `gci *dog* | ? Extension -in (cat .\extensions.txt)` this first checks for files with "dog" in their name, and then checks for the file extensions. if you need something other than dog, with regex, just do `gci | ? { $_.BaseName -match "<regex>" -and $_.Extension -in (cat .\extensions.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

Far easier than listing each file **extension**, Windows has the concept of **kind**. For example in Windows Explorer, to search for all *filenames* containing "dog" and of *kind* "image" (or "picture"; they both work), enter the following as search parameters: `filename:*dog* AND kind:image`. The asterisk wild-cards are not always needed.

Of course, that only works for registered image extensions, but one can easily add any missing extension to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` with Regedit:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *rege* and select *regedit.exe*.
- Copy `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` and paste into the navigation bar to go to that location.
- If a value for an extension is missing, e.g., *.png*,

  - Right-click the right pane.
  - Select *New > String Value*.
  - Enter the extension, including leading period (full stop).
  - Double-click that value and enter *picture* for *Value data*.

[image: Registry key for Kind]

These changes take effect immediately; a search for that extension as *kind:image* or *kind:picture* will now succeed.

See also [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293865/is-it-possible-to-find-all-the-video-files-using-powershell) for such a search using PowerShell.

You might consider one of the third-party tools, such as Mythicsoft's fremium [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) or [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/agent-ransack/).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `kind:image` in this case because `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` doesn't have all of the OP's desired fieltypes mapped to `image` .

Comment: @KeithMiller, The OP might very well have them in that key, added by an application, or could easily add them... as the answer has been amended. This allows flexible Windows Search, without need to resort to additional tools.

Comment: True, and I'm a big fan of using `kind` and avoiding 3rd-party tools as well. But many in work settings don't have Admin privileges (needed to modify HKLM) or they might want a more "portable " script that doesn't rely on non-default registry entries. I would check the *KindMap* using: `((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap).PSObject.Properties | ? Name -match '^\.' | ? Value -eq 'picture' | select -expand name | sort) | Out-String | Out-Clipboard` (or save to variable, save filter list to another variable, and go with `Compare-Object) :D

Answer (score 0):

Put all your extensions as listed on the question in a file and save it. Let assume your filename is `myextensions.txt`. Use the following cmdlets:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\myextensions.txt | foreach { dir *dog* -Include "*$_" }
```

**Explanation:**

- `Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\myextensions.txt`: reads the file's content
- `| foreach { dir *dog* -Include "*$_" }`: the result of the previous cmdlt is applied for each line (extension) to list files that have 'dog' and the extension as part of their name(s).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-Content` to put the file list with extensions into an `array` variable. Next use `Get-ChildItem` with its `-File` parameter to specifically target file objects. Then, route the results through a `ForEach-Object` loop to display both the ***full file path and file name for files whose extensions match*** those in the array variable.

### PowerShell

```
$keyword = "dog";
$ext = Get-Content -Path "C:\Folder\ExtList.txt";
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {If($_.Extension -in $ext -and $_.Name -match $keyword){$_.FullName}};
##Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {If($_.Extension -in $ext -and $_.Name -match $keyword){$_.FullName}};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3)
- [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3)
- [about_If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone ... I assume you're already familiar with `Get-ChildItem` but commented out line is for recursive search rather than just in one specific of the current directory you run the command. You can use that commented out line in place of line 2 if you need to search recursively.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, put the extensions in a data file, but then I'd go with:

```
$Keyword     = 'dog'
$ExtList     = 'c:\Data\imageExtensions.txt'
$RegEx4Match = '^.*{0}.*\.({1})$' -f $Keyword , ((Get-Content $ExtList) -join '|' -replace '\.')

Get-ChildItem -File | where Name -match $RegEx4Match
```

With Get-ChildItem, you can use the `-Path` parameter to search a directory other than the current working directory. To include sub-folders, add the `-Recurse` parameter.